# The cardinal directions and prepositions

Tags: prepositions

Is it okay to use the cardinal directions without prepositions as follows?

> ***East*** of Peter was red sun rising.

> ***North*** of him was a big red star shining.

> Turning his head ***west***, he saw five stars shining upon his eyes.

> Where is Peter?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the cardinal directions, but presumably Peter has only one head? "Turning his head [to the] west, he saw..."

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I revised the sentence as you said.